# Power issue - Dead appliances, but no tripped breakers

Tags: electrical

I have been having some issues where appliances like washing machines (yes, multiple!!) and a dryer and a power switch* have just died on me. There was no break to the circuit - as in every other thing in the house was working, no breakers were tripped.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing all these electrical issues?

Edit:
*By power switch, I really mean it's more like a ACDC wall wart. It's wall mounted, and plugged into a socket.

Comment: does the outlet still have power?

Comment: What do you mean by a “power switch” dying? This is a mechanical switch for lights? Something electronic?

Comment: @ratchet freak : yes, the outlets still work. I even tried the sniff test - no burnt smell there.

Comment: Was the dryer that died gas or electric?  Also, do you have voltmeter or can you borrow/beg one for that matter?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - Dryer was electric. Your handle made me think too - my place is on 3 phase power. Is that relevant? Will try and obtain a voltmeter

Comment: Breakers don't trip for every electrical problem.  It may matter, why are you on 3-phase? NYC?

Comment: @George -- that is quite relevant!  Do you know if you are on a wye or a high leg delta system?  Also, is this a single family house or an apartment (if the latter, is it in a high-rise?)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - I live in Australia. It's a standalone house. We have 3-phase power due to a ducted reverse cycle air conditioning system. The summers here are a killer (but then, with the system, so is my electricity bill...)

Comment: Are light bulbs getting brighter and dimmer mysteriously as you turn things on and off?

Comment: There was one CFL twirly light that I noticed is always dim when switched on but gets brighter over a few minutes. Mind you, it was there since 7 years ago, so I dismissed it as age. Danger sign? Also, got a voltmeter. Readings are fluctuating between 240-249VAC.